# Importing multiple exce files including sheets into 1 excel file

Tags: python, excel, pandas, python-os

I have 5 Excel files, each file contains 8 sheets, each sheet contains around 30 rows. So this means 1 file has in total 30 x 8 = 240 rows. Is there a speedy trick I can use to combine all these 5 files (including sheets) into 1 Excelfile with in total 240 x 5 rows = 1200 rows?

This is my current code:

```
import os
import pandas as pd

files = os.listdir('c:\data\KM\Desktop\my_folder') 
 
os.chdir(r'c:\data\KM\Desktop\my_folder')

df = pd.DataFrame()

for file in files:
    if file.endswith('.xlsx'):
        df = df.append(pd.read_excel(file))
df.head() 
df.to_excel('all_files.xlsx')
```

Now with this code I have 2 problems:

1. From all the files I just get the 1st sheet. So its merges 8 sheets in total instead of 40 (8x5) :(
2. For every file it copies also the column headers, this needs to be done just for the 1st file. All the files and sheets have the same column names.

Appreciate your help all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`read_excel`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.read_excel.html) with `sheet_name=None` for all sheets, join together by [`concat`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.concat.html) for list of DataFrames and last use it again for one big DataFrame:

```
import glob

files = glob.glob(r'c:/data/KM/Desktop/my_folder/*.xlsx') 
dfs = (pd.concat(pd.read_excel(fp, sheet_name=None)) for fp in files)
dfbig = pd.concat(dfs, ignore_index=True)
```

Edit: For remove last sheetname convert orderdict to lists of DataFrame and remiove last by indexing:

```
files = glob.glob(r'D:/Dropbox/work-joy/so/files/*.xlsx')
dfs = (pd.concat([v for k, v in pd.read_excel(fp, sheet_name=None).items()][:-1]) 
                 for fp in files)
df = pd.concat(dfs, ignore_index=True)
```

Comment: Aha this worked great! thank you. 2 questions. 1. It still copies all the columns of every sheet. How to get rid of that? 2. Is it possible to exclude sheets also?

Comment: @Premier12 - What is name of sheetname for exclude?

Comment: Different names, for every file I need to exclude the latest file. they all have different names.

Comment: @Premier12 - Do you think latest sheetname?

Comment: No, Im 100% certain its the last sheet for every file.

Comment: I get: `XLRDError: Unsupported format, or corrupt file: Expected BOF record; found b'PK\x05\x06\x00\x00\x00\x00'`

Comment: @Premier12 - What is your pandas version?

Comment: @jazrael pandas version 1.0.5

Comment: @Premier12 - It failed only for second code? First working well?

Comment: @jazrael lol thats weird the first code also gives the same error now. Before it worked.

Comment: @Premier12 - I think there is some proble m with data, unfortunately :(

Comment: Ah I see, I got an other wrong excel file in the folder. Okay the first code works. The second also works but when I add `r'D:\Dropbox\work-joy\so\files\the_newfile.xlsx'')` to your second code I get ValueError `No object to concatenate`

Comment: Aha I see it works. Thank you very much. Excuses for asking you to much, but the columnheaders are still being exported for every sheet :(